# Redimensionar array PHP

Tags: php, array

Con el siguiente código pretendo pasar el contenido de un `array` con caracteres a su correspondiente valor en la tabla *ASCII*. Tengo un problema a la hora de acceder al `array` porque no puedo redimensionarlo. **¿Cómo podría hacerlo?**

```
 $data = array("H","O","L","A","M","U","N","D","O");

 for($x = 0; $x < count($data); $x++ ){

     $ascii = array(ord($data[$x]));
     echo $ascii[$x];
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

El error que vi al ejecutar tu código es que en la tercera línea en vez de añadir una posición al array estabas reiniciando el array en cada pasada del bucle, por lo que siempre estabas guardando todos los valores en el campo 0 del array.

Corregí el código y así me quedó:

```
<?php
   $data = array("H","O","L","A","M","U","N","D","O");

   for($x = 0; $x < count($data); $x++ ){

       $ascii[$x] = ord($data[$x]);
       echo $ascii[$x];

   }
?>
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Un saludo :)

Comment: Una pregunta por qué no haces  `$ascii[$x] = array(ord($data[$x]));` y en su lugar haces  `$ascii[$x] = ord($data[$x]);`

Comment: ¿No hay que especificar a la hora de declarar la variable `$ascii` que es de tipo array?

Comment: no. De hecho php te permite mantener dentro de un array enteros, cadenas, caracteres, objetos... Ademas, no necesitas "redimensionar" el array. Solo añade un elemento directamente, con `$data[] = $value`

Comment: Hola nauumb si en vez de usar $ascii[$x] = ord($data[$x]);, el cual te crea un array de cadenas ([ "27", "3", ...]), usaras $ascii[$x] = array(ord($data[$x])); tendrías un array de arrays  [ ["27"] , ["3"] , ... ]

Answer (score 4):

Podrías manejar el `array` con `foreach`. Es mucho más cómodo para lo que necesitas hacer. También lo suyo sería que declarases el `array $ascii` como `array` y fuera del bucle para que no tengas problemas de que deje de ser accesible y luego lo vas llenando dentro del bucle con `array_push()`.

```
$data = array("H","O","L","A","M","U","N","D","O");
$ascii = array();

foreach($data as $letra){   
    array_push($ascii, ord($letra));    
}

print_r($ascii);
```

Answer (score 4):

PHP no es como c, en el sentido de la memoria en los arrays. En php puedes añadir un elemento directamente al array. Solo hay que indicarle lo siguiente:

```
  $data = [];

  $data[] =  "cadena1";
  $data[] =  "cadena2";
```

Ademas es posible añadir datos con una key, lo que en PHP denomina "array asociativo":

```
  $data = [];

  $data["key1"] =  "cadena1";
  $data["key2"] =  "cadena2";
```

Ademas, podrias cambiar el codigo de esta manera:

```
function toAscii($n)
{
    return(ord($n));
}


$data = array("H","O","L","A","M","U","N","D","O");
$ascii = array_map("toAscii", $data);
```

En php tienes la funcion `array_map` , que te devuelve un array en el que se ha ejecutado por cada elemento, la funcion que le pasemos. En este caso, te he definido una funcion que devuelve un elemento convertido al ascii correspondiente. Array_map ejecutara esa funcion en cada uno de los elementos, devolviendote el array que quieres.

Si imprimes el array $ascii que resulta de ejecutar este codigo, veras el siguiente resultado:

```
Array (
    [0] => 72
    [1] => 79
    [2] => 76
    [3] => 65
    [4] => 77
    [5] => 85
    [6] => 78
    [7] => 68
    [8] => 79 )
```

Comment: No veo de una forma clara la diferencia entre recorrer un array con un `for` o `foreach` a usar la función `array_map`

Comment: En este ejemplo quizas no se ve mucho. Pero la diferencia mas interesante es que con el `array_map` encapsulas la logica que harias dentro del foreach. Asi no corres peligro de sobreescribir ciertas variables en el foreach que te afecten en otra parte de codigo, ya que el ambito de las variables esta en la funcion callback, y no en el propio foreach.

Comment: De gran ayuda esta explicación, muchisimas gracias.